# return python lxml text as string not single item list - from xml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

Using Microsoft Books.xml https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85)

Sample of first entry.

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Trying to extract all book titles from id's with an odd id. Capturing the id and title as Key, value in dictionary

So far I have this working except all titles return as a single item list.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('books.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

data = {}
for child in root.findall('book'):
    for k,v in child.items():
        for title in child.iter('title'):
            if int(v.split('k')[1]) % 2 != 0:
                if k not in data:
                    data[v] = []
                data[v].append(title.text)
            
print(data['bk101'])
```

*Output*

```
{'bk101': ["XML Developer's Guide"], 'bk103': ['Maeve Ascendant'], 'bk105': ['The Sundered Grail'], 'bk107': ['Splish Splash'], 'bk109': ['Paradox Lost'], 'bk111': ['MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide']}
```

*Desired Output*

```
{'bk101': "XML Developer's Guide", 'bk103': 'Maeve Ascendant', 'bk105': 'The Sundered Grail', 'bk107': 'Splish Splash', 'bk109': 'Paradox Lost', 'bk111': 'MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide'}
```

How can I return the title as text not as a list?

**Note** I can pull them from my dictionary as text with

```
print(data['bk101'][0])
```

However, would prefer them saved into the dictionary as text not extracted later.

**Edit** I realise its because I am creating a list as a default value when checking if key exists. However, cannot us a **None** type as a placeholder to avoid the list side effect.

Realise I probably should be using *fromkeys* as in this answer [SO to initialising a dict with keys and empty value](https://print(data%5B%27bk101%27%5D%5B0%5D))

But how do I do this in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect multiple `<title>` tags per book, there is no need to use a list and you can just assign the value of `title.text` rather than appending it. Additionally, iterating over `child.items()` is unnecessary when you know you specifically want the `id` attribute. It could have caused problems if there were other attributes, since they won't be in the same format to get split.

The simplified code based on the assumption that every `<book>` has an `id` and a `<title>` child (like in your sample XML) is as follows:

```py
for child in root.findall('book'):
    book_id = child.get('id')
    if int(book_id.split('k')[1]) % 2 != 0:
        data[book_id] = child.find('title').text

print(data)
```

This gives the output:

```
{'bk101': "XML Developer's Guide", 'bk103': 'Maeve Ascendant', 'bk105': 'The Sundered Grail', 'bk107': 'Splish Splash', 'bk109': 'Paradox Lost', 'bk111': 'MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide'}
```

If it is possible for `<title>` to be missing, `find()` can return `None`, so an additional if condition would be needed.

If you expect multiple `<title>` tags per `<book>`, it would be better to have a list and use `child.iter('title')` like in your question. This would implicitly handle the missing title case too, since the code inside the loop won't run.